# Padding a number with leading zeros in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the sample answer I've found.

Could anyone explain the code below step by step?

The 'str = "0" + str' part is most confusing.

```
const fillZero = function (n, w) {
    let str = String(n);
    for (let i = str.length; i < w; i++) {
      str = "0" + str;
    }
    return str;
}

  console.log(fillZero(5, 3)); // 005
  console.log(fillZero(12, 3)); // 012
  console.log(fillZero(123, 3)); // 123
```

Comment: You can use `String.padStart` javascript function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: What about it is confusing? If the value of `str` is `"5"` then `"0" + "5"` is `"05"`.

Comment: For 3 fixed - then a simpler script is : `const pad = num => ("00"+num).slice(-3);`

Answer (score 0):

With `str = "0" + str` he is using string concatenation. For example, if the string was `Hello`, after that line of code it will be `0Hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using i in the for loop, most people would set i = 0, you are setting it to the length of characters of "n". So as long as n < w (w = 3, according to above), you will be adding 0 + n until n = w.

in the first example: `n = 1, w = 3`.

`str = 0 + 5` after first iteration  THEN
`str = 0 + 05` after second iteration

`i` is no longer lesser than `3`, so final output is `005`.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail!